# Why is the html viewed through developer tools different from the html fetched through beautifulsoup?

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

Hi i am making a program that scrapes jobs from stackoverflow accordingly when i enter a specific keyword.

To do that, I need to know the maximum number of pages when you enter a specific keyword.
However, the html content viewed through the developer tool and the html imported through beautifulsoup are different and are having a problem.

For example, let's call the keyword'vue'.

The url is as follows:
https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?q=vue

The number of pages checked through developer tools is 2.
[image]

However, if you check the number of pages after entering the following code and outputting the result, the maximum number of pages is 43.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = "https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?q=vue"
result = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text,"html.parser")
print(soup)
```

[image]

I need to load the content corresponding to 2 pages related to vue, but I am having a problem of scraping not only this content but also unrelated content.

I did not know where the problem occurred, so I asked questions. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The developer tools shows the _DOM represented as HTML markup_. If this differs from the actual HTML response text (“View Page Source”) .. well, there are a few reasons including dynamic DOM changes and ‘fixing’ HTML source markup. If the “View Page Source” — also compare with cURL — differs then it might be different input provided to the server (eg. cookies, headers).

Comment: Sorry but I could not see the differences between 2 images, they all have an `a` tag with `title="page 43 of 43"`. Could you point out the differences?

Comment: @dongnhan  
I accidentally uploaded the same image. I'm sorry. I've revised the post and would appreciate it if you read it again.

Answer (score 0):

In the request headers there's one called `user-agent` identifies which program is performing the request. [Read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent)

[image: user-agent in request header]

To pretend making a request from the browser, you could try to set the `user-agent` header to this Chrome User Agent string:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: I've tried with Postman and the HTML result appeared as I was requesting from the browser

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation. First of all, I modified the user-agent with the user-agent you posted in the comment. Is this all you need to do? Since I'm a beginner, I'm not sure exactly what to do to get the desired result. If the question is too vague, you don't need to answer it. Thank you for just answering.

Comment: solved the problem. I modified the code as below and got the desired result. Thank you so much for the answer!headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0'}
    url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?q=vue'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text, 'html.parser')